# strange behaviour of `eval` in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have encountered a strange behaviour by the `eval` command that I can't understand. When I try use eval to run a command whose name is stored in a variable I get strange results.

The array `mCallBackCont` has the value `::postLayRep1||mainTableView sendToLoads` under `insert`, so that<sup>*</sup>:

```
>>set mCallBackCont(insert)
::postLayRep1||mainTableView sendToLoads
```

Where `::postLayRep1||mainTableView` is an object of a class that has a `sendToLoads` public method

When I try to do one of the following:

```
eval {::postLayRep1||mainTableView sendToLoads}
eval ::postLayRep1||mainTableView sendToLoads
eval "::postLayRep1||mainTableView sendToLoads"
eval $mCallBackCont(insert)
eval "mCallBackCont(insert)"
```

I get the correct behaviour, but When I use

```
eval {$mCallBackCont(insert)}
```

I get the error:

```
invalid command name "::postLayRep1||mainTableView sendToLoads"
```

When I try the same with a regular proc with no argument:

```
>>proc test_proc {} {return}
>>set a test_proc
>>eval {$a}
```

Everything works, but when I add argument, the same happens:

```
>>proc test_proc {val} {puts $val}
>>set a [list test_proc 1]
test_proc 1
>>eval {$a}
invalid command name "test_proc 1"
```

Since the eval command is part of a code from a library I'm using I can't change it, the only thing I can determine is the value of `mCallBackCont(insert)`. The code in the library is:

```
if { [catch {eval {$mCallBackCont(insert) [namespace tail $this] $type $name $n $redraw}} e] } {
          error "Wrong number of arguments for the procedure \"$mCallBackCont(insert)\". Should be \"table type name num redraw\"."
}
```

- Why does `eval {$var}` works for procs but not for methods of a class (I guess it somehow relates to the fact that the proc is a 1-word command, while a method is more complicated)?
- In what way can I set the value of `mCallBackCont(insert)` so that it works correctly?

---

<sup>*</sup> - I have tried to put the value in `mCallBackCont(insert)` both a list and as one string surrounded by `""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, Tcl command names can have spaces in. Or in fact nearly any other character; the only ones you have to be careful of are `:`s because `::` is a namespace separator, and a leading `::` is fine as it just means that it is a fully-qualified name.

Because of that, `::postLayRep1||mainTableView sendToLoads` is a legal but unusual command name. If you put the name in a variable, you can then use a read from that variable just as if it is a command name:

```
$theVariableContainingTheCommandName
```

Using an array element is nothing special in this regard.

Now, if you want to instead treat that as a script, you pass it to `eval` like this:

```
eval $theVariableContainingTheScript
```

The real problem you're having is that you instead are doing:

```
eval {$theVariableContainingTheScript}
```

That is defined to be *exactly* identical to doing just:

```
$theVariableContainingTheScript
```

That won't ever do what you appear to want. Looking at the code that's causing you the problem:

```
if { [catch {eval {$mCallBackCont(insert) [namespace tail $this] $type $name $n $redraw}} e] } {
    error "Wrong number of arguments for the procedure \"$mCallBackCont(insert)\". Should be \"table type name num redraw\"."
}
```

In this case, the value in the variable has to be the name of a command, and not just a script fragment. The simplest fix for you is to create an alias which binds in the extra arguments:

```
interp alias {} callBackForInsert {} ::postLayRep1||mainTableView sendToLoads
```

Then you can use `callBackForInsert` just as if it was the combination of calling `::postLayRep1||mainTableView` with the first argument `sendToLoads`. It's effectively a named partial application. Alternatively, you can use a helper procedure:

```
proc callBackForInsert args {
    return [uplevel 1 {::postLayRep1||mainTableView sendToLoads} $args]
}
```

But that's both uglier and slower in this simple case. Better in 8.6 is to use `tailcall`:

```
proc callBackForInsert args {
    tailcall ::postLayRep1||mainTableView sendToLoads {*}$args
}
```

But that is still slower than an alias because of the overhead of the extra stack frame manipulation.

---

However, the *nicest* fix if you can is to alter the library so it uses the callback like this (assuming Tcl 8.5 or later):

```
if { [catch {eval {{*}$mCallBackCont(insert) [namespace tail $this] $type $name $n $redraw}} e] } {
    error "Wrong number of arguments for the procedure \"$mCallBackCont(insert)\". Should be \"table type name num redraw\"."
}
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
if { [catch {{*}$mCallBackCont(insert) [namespace tail $this] $type $name $n $redraw} e] } {
    error "Wrong number of arguments for the procedure \"$mCallBackCont(insert)\". Should be \"table type name num redraw\"."
}
```

A good rule of thumb is that there's hardly ever a reason to use `eval` in modern Tcl code; a `{*}`-expansion is virtually always closer to what is intended.

If you're stuck with 8.4 but can change the library code, you can do this instead:

```
if { [catch {eval $mCallBackCont(insert) {[namespace tail $this] $type $name $n $redraw}} e] } {
    error "Wrong number of arguments for the procedure \"$mCallBackCont(insert)\". Should be \"table type name num redraw\"."
}
```

This uses the fact that `eval` will concatenate its arguments before feeding them back through the Tcl script evaluation engine.

---

The combination of aliases, expansion, `tailcall` and (not used in this answer) ensembles lets you do awesome stuff with very little code, allowing complicated remixing of arguments without having to load yourself down with lots of helper procedures.

Comment: And now the challenge has began, trying to change the code of a library with no apparent owner, in an organization that still only uses Tcl 8.4.

Comment: Now that I can't help. Aliases (the first thing I proposed) work if you're stuck for other options.